# Showing hidden div when mouse over

Tags: php, jquery, html, pushstate

How to make php-script restart (new GET-request), after changing URL section using `history.pushState`. Need to refresh part of the page (`<div>`), which  is selected from database using 
changed part of the URL.
`<div>` is initially hidden (`style="visibility:hidden;"`) and gets visible (`style="visibility:visible;"`) on `mouseenter` on menu-link.

There are two links in menu showing different content on `mouseenter` so need to change $_GET["sect"] i.e. part of the URL, so php script can choose right database record.

site URL: http://site.com?sect=**section**

**section** -- changed part.

in result: URL changes, but div content -- not.

Sorry my english & low skill.

Answer (score 0):

To change the inner html of your element you should use jquery's html() method:

http://api.jquery.com/html/

If the url switching is working fine then all you need to do is to implement this method.

Good luck!